# Is the "Star Trek Voyager" episode "Threshold" named after traveling at Warp 10?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Season 2 of *Star Trek Voyager*, episode 15 was called "Threshold" and it was about traveling at Warp 10, wasn't it?

Comment: Other than "Yes, it was" what kind of an answer are you expecting?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.

> VOY, Episode 2x15
>
> Production number: 132
>
> First aired: 29 January 1996

Per [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Threshold_%28episode%29):

> **Tom Paris is in an experimental shuttlecraft, attempting to break the warp 10 barrier.** He brings the shuttle up to warp 9.95, when the nacelles are suddenly ripped from the shuttle and it seemingly explodes. Paris appears, sitting on the holodeck floor, as if nothing happened; it was all a simulation. Harry Kim looks despondent, and B'Elanna Torres responds matter-of-factly, "You're dead."

Comment: -1 for lack of unicorns

Comment: +1 for not mentioning the giant-catfish lovin' between superevolved Tom and Cap'n Janeway.

Comment: -1 for encouraging such abject nonsense.